# Dropwizard java.lang.NoSuchMethodException in registered resource

Tags: rest, jersey, jetty, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm using the latest stable version of Dropwizard framework with Java 7. I'm trying to use a resource class and whatever I have tried I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
WARN  [2016-06-13 14:51:26,664] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: /users/list
! java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in my.test.package.endpoint.TestResource class.
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:179) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:993) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! ... 65 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
! 1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in my.test.package.endpoint.TestResource class.
! 
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:995) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:963) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1055) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1047) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:170) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:301) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) ~[jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139) ~[jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
! ... 41 common frames omitted
! Causing: javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
! 1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in my.test.package.endpoint.TestResource class.
! 
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:487) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) ~[dropwizard-jetty-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83) ~[jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:364) ~[jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:132) ~[dropwizard-jetty-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) ~[dropwizard-servlets-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:43) ~[dropwizard-jersey-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:38) ~[dropwizard-jersey-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119) ~[guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133) ~[guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130) ~[guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203) ~[guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130) ~[guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240) ~[metrics-jetty9-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51) ~[dropwizard-jetty-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) ~[jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
WARN  [2016-06-13 14:51:26,665] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: Could not send response error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in my.test.package.endpoint.TestResource class.
```

Although i have read many similar issues and tried every possible solution. The problem still exists.

Inside Application class:

```
    @Override
        public void run(ServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
                throws Exception {
           final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
           final DBI jdbi = factory
          .build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(),"as400");
            final TestDAOdao = jdbi.onDemand(TestDAO.class);

            environment.jersey().register(new TestResource(dao));
    }
```

TestResource.class

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource {

    private  final TestDAO testDAO;

    public TestResource (TestDAO testDAO) {
      this.testDAO= testDAO;
    }



    @Path("/list")
    @GET
    public List<TestDto> list() {
        ......


    }
}
```

My TestDao.class

```
public interface TestDao{

    @Mapper(TestMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery (".... ")
    List<Test> list();   
}
```

Comment: The problem lies in your `gr.generali.mygen.api.rs.v1.endpoint.UserRs`, declaration, can you post that in your question?

Comment: Im sorry i didnt noticed. I renamed it in order to be more clear to you the names i used. UserRs is my TestResource class.

Comment: Are you using Guice to inject? If so, where is your Guice configuration. My guess is Guice is also trying to create the class. Maybe you set up scanning of packages?

Comment: I don't think that the issue has to do with the guice without being so sure. In fact im new in dropwizard and im trying to understand how the whole thing works. However i have initialized Guice. I dont face issues with the injection or when the resource has no arg constructor. And it seems to can register the TestResource.class without issue. But when im making the get call from browser it's like it  skips the registered resource and trying to create a new one with the default constructor.

Comment: As i can figure out jersy uses the default analyzer which "rejects" classes which have neither default constructor nor with injected arguments. And I dont have either of them.

Comment: This should work just fine. I have an example application with DW 1.0.0-rc3 running here. Try and write up an example that can compile so we can reproduce the problem locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!

Thank you all for your answers.
The problem layed in guice initialization.
My code was:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<ServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        super.initialize(bootstrap);
        guiceBundle = GuiceBundle.<ServiceConfiguration>newBuilder()
                  .addModule(new MyBinder())
                  .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
                  .setConfigClass(ServiceConfiguration.class)
                  .build();
        bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
        bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/dist", "/dist", "index.html"));

    }
```

when i commented out this line:

```
.enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
```

it worked fine. I didn't post it in the first place because i couldn't imagine that this could be the source of evil, until i created a sample project from scratch.